# How come AJ is the winner in this Omaha scenario?

Tags: omaha

I thought in Omaha you have to play 2 cards.  If the 2 board cards are higher than the Jack, then wouldn't that disqualify the hand because the Jack cannot outkick the board? I was under the assumption that you have to play the best 5 cards (2 from your hand and 3 from the board).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Omaha, you create your best five card hand by using precisely three community cards and precisely two hole cards.

In this example, your best hand is AA22J, which uses A22 from the community cards and AJ from your hand. Player 2's best hand is KKQQA, which uses AKQ from the community cards and KQ from his hand.  Since your two pair has the bigger pair (AA), you win.

Comment: Don't you have to use the best 5 cards available though?  If this was hold'em, then the winning hand would be AA22K and the Jack wouldn't play.  But because this is Omaha, wouldn't that disqualify the hand because you are unable to play 2 cards?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to play two cards?  You just have to imagine that at showdown, you throw away two cards from your hand, and replace two community cards with your cards -- that'd be your five card hand.

Comment: Your hand must be made from exactly two cards from your hand and exactly three from the board--whether or not there might be some other better set of five cards is irrelevant.